# SSRS Reports - Moving from one cube to another

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I've been tasked with moving some reports/solutions that point to our OLD cube to point to our NEW cube.

The structures are the same but the name of dimensions/measures have changed.

What would the best tool for the job be or would it need a manual process? If manual, can someone please point me in the direction of some useful resources to help.

Thanks.

Comment: There is not a tool that discovers changes and modify the deployed reports as required. Besides modify your report to take the new measures and dimensions names, you have to modify the datasources in order to connect to your new cube.

Comment: Hope this link can be helpful: Manually process the TFS data warehouse and analysis services cube  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/report/admin/manually-process-data-warehouse-and-cube